# Where to report suggestions for SnakeMake

Tags: snakemake

Where should suggestions to SnakeMake developers be posted?

The suggestions I would like to make are:

1. Indicate on the SnakeMake user guide web site where to post suggestions.
2. Indicate on the SnakeMake user guide web site that questions about SnakeMake should be posted on stackOverflow.

(Or are they there and I missed them?)

Comment: Only programming-related questions are allowed here.  If they didn't make that abundantly clear on their website, then they have misled you. Go ahead and delete this now and go check on their website for directions.

Comment: All of this is clearly stated in snakemake's documentation under the section: support. https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: You could raise an issue on the bitbucket page or edit the documentation yourself and raise a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

As @nv_wu [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492328/where-to-report-suggestions-for-snakemake#comment78028455_45492328), support channels are listed in the ["Support" section](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#support) of the documentation:

> - In case of questions, please post on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snakemake).
> - To discuss with other Snakemake users, you can use the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/snakemake).
> - For bugs and feature requests, please use the [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues).
> - For contributions, visit Snakemake on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake) and read the [guidelines](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/contributing.html#project-info-contributing).

In general, requests for help should go here on Stack Overflow rather than the mailing list. Since Snakemake is open source, bug reports ("Issues"), feature requests (also filed as bitbucket "Issues"), suggestions, and general developer chatter belong on [bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake).